# Crystal Reports - Order of execution of multiple commands

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to know if there's a way to alter the order of how the commands in a report are executed.
The commands are not linked between them in any way.

For instance, I have two commands:

- Command 1: Obtains a common list from a table. (Select * from Customers)
- Command 2: Obtains footer information. (Select version, logo from ReportInfo)

I would like Command 2 executing first and then Command 1.

Is it possible to configure in CR the order of execution of the commands. Now it's executing in the order the were created. But i would like to customize them.

Thanks.

Crystal Report version 13.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subreports. They would process in the order of their location within the main report.

It is not clear why you need to control the order of execution. Perhaps combine the whole logic into a single VIEW or STORED PROCEDURE instead of using multiple Commands.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried a Subreport but it doesn't work for this problem. The data I would like to retrieve in the second command is just footer -logo and version info-. Logo image is selected from the database. It's not related to the main data of the report. I've asked here the main problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497513/crystal-reports-second-command-not-executing-when-first-command-doesnt-retrie